# using <ul> for dynamic forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms, styling

I am building a form where I have some elements that need to appear or disappear when you click another yes/no input.  I need some styling help.

See this JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TdnZp/11/

Everything technically works the way I want.  Notice when you click yes/no, another form element shows up or hides, and the space taken by the element disappears.  This is good, but I also need the input boxes and labels to be in nice columns, up and down, not staggered like they are now.

Also when the new element comes in, I would like all the elements below it to smoothly slide down to make room instead of jumping down instantaneously, the same for when the elements disappear, the lower ones slide up smoothly to fill in.

Does anyone know how to do these 2 things?  If I should be using different HTML elements besides `<ul>` then please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: `.slideToggle()` might be better than `.fade()` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.slideUp` and `.slideDown` animation if you want the new form to slide in.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TdnZp/12/)

See below,

```
$('[name="label"]').change(function(){
    if ($('[name="label"]:checked').val() == "yes"){
        $('#bl').slideDown('slow');
    }else{
        $('#bl').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

**Edit:** You need to modify your markup and css for the alignment and styling. See below code and modify it as you wanted it..

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TdnZp/15/)

**CSS:**

```
#list li { padding: 2px; }
#list input { margin: 1px; }
div.form-label { display: inline-block; width: 100px; font-weight: bold;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>
            <div class="form-label">
                <label for="label">Label:</label>
            </div>
            <input type="radio" name="label" value="yes" />Yes
            <input type="radio" name="label" value="no" />No
        </li>
        <li id="bl">
            <div class="form-label">
                <label for="label_cost">Cost:</label>
            </div>
            <input name="label_cost" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="form-label">
                <label for="another_one">Another One:</label>
            </div>
            <input name="another_one" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

The spacing you want can be achieved by setting label widths, and the slide effect you want can but achieved using slideDown instead of fadeIn.

Comment: I tried using the `<label>` element and setting the width in css, but it doesn't seem to be working, here: http://jsfiddle.net/TdnZp/14/

Comment: label are inline tags and width will not be set to labels unless if you set a `block` like style.